# What is a word I can use instead of "the other" when referring to an unknown person?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

I am writing a scene where a character interacts with someone he cannot see and does not know - in essence anonymous stranger, with no visual aids. Are there any other words or phrases I can use to refer to the second party instead of "the other"? Because of the lack of visuals, I cannot say "the man with the hat" or something similar, and since positions relative to each other are important, I cannot accurately depict their motions/actions relative to each other in detail without using "the other." A lot of motions are going on and I'm sick of using the same repetitive phrase.

For example, "The other flipped him over their shoulder."

Either a phrase or a single word replacement works fine, I just want to have something that conveys the meaning without giving away detail that the character doesn't have that isn't "the other."

Comment: Perhaps, [Jane/John Doe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Doe)?

Comment: [writers.se] might be a better place to ask for help avoiding repetitive phrasing.

Comment: You can describe their relationship, e.g. "his assailant", "his opponent", etc.

Comment: I did not see that there was writing, thank you! I'll try your suggestions and see how it goes. @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

Why not call them "the stranger"?